# Partial template in Jade/Pug with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, partials

I am trying to create view with 2 blocks. Each block had different real time data source. When I use Jade`s include within main view, :

```
extends ../layout

block content
 link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='/stylesheets/people.css')
 include ../store/peopleTemplate.pug
```

I get error

```
Cannot read property 'people' of undefined.
```

The reason is because the data is still loading. If exclude that include and instead in function that revives data use

```
res.render(template, {  data:localData });
```

The template is not added to the view.

How to add 2 or more partial views with dynamic data from different sources to 1 view? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with mixins.

**layout.pug**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    ...
  body
    block content
```

**pets-partial.pug**

```
mixin petslist(pets)
  ul
    each pet in pets
      li #{pet}
```

**pets.pug**

```
extends layout

include pets-partial

block content
  h1 Dogs
  +petslist(dogs)

  h1 Cats
  +petslist(cats)
```

https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html

In jade the syntax is slightly different then in pug 2.

Answer (score 4):

After extensive research, Pug/Jade Template engine does not support dynamic template rendering or usage of multiple partials within one view. Handlebars was recommended for this scenario.